# Deleting an element in a database based on the HTML-element that is clicked

Tags: c#, html, database, reference, element

I am creating a "Notes" web app. For every Note in my database, I am creating a div-container showing the text content stored in my database.

I want each div-container to have a delete-button, which is supposed to delete that specific Note immediately from my database. How can I accomplish this?

The Database function for deleting my Note ready. My source code is currently something like this:

// my delete-function in my database class

```
public Boolean DeleteNote(Note n) {

    // ... deletes Note n from db

}
```

// my HTML element displaying each Note in the database

```
.@foreach(Note n in myNotes) {

    <div class="container note">

        <button onclick="**???????**">Delete Note</button>

        <p>@n.Text</p>

    </div>

}
```

PS. I am using C# and .NET MVC if that is relevant.

Comment: Yes you do it let me show you an example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your delete note method is at the controller level, you would probably want to write a function that makes an Ajax call into your method and removes the div from the page of your method returns true.

Iirc .NET MVC comes with jQuery. That has some really good documentation.